# PythonNet "No module named ..." exception for my module but not numpy

Tags: python.net

I'm using C#/Python.Included, which imports PythonNet. In  a fresh project, the C# code is:

```
using Python.Included;
using Python.Runtime;

Console.WriteLine( Environment.CurrentDirectory );
string modname = "testImport.py";
Console.WriteLine( File.Exists( modname ) );

Installer.SetupPython();
PythonEngine.Initialize();

using (Py.GIL())
{
    dynamic np = Py.Import( "numpy" );
    Console.WriteLine( np.pi );

    dynamic mine = Py.Import( modname );
    mine.testImport();
}
```

The `testImport.py` file contains this simple function:

```
def testImport():
    print("something")
```

The outout:

```
C:\GIT\TestPyImport\bin\Debug\net7.0
True
3.141592653589793
Unhandled exception. Python.Runtime.PythonException: No module named 'testImport'
   at Python.Runtime.PythonException.ThrowLastAsClrException()
   at Python.Runtime.NewReferenceExtensions.BorrowOrThrow(NewReference& reference)
   at Python.Runtime.PyModule.Import(String name)
   at Python.Runtime.Py.Import(String name)
   at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in C:\GIT\TestPyImport\Program.cs:line 16
```

Why would `numpy` import just fine (evidenced by the printing of `pi`) while my simple module (which is in the current directory evidenced by `File.Exists(modname)`) not even import?

I am quite new to Python, so my guess is that it has something to do with the way one must declare a module that's to be imported, but I just don't know.

**EDIT**: I changed methodology, replacing the `Py.Import` with:

```
    //dynamic mine = Py.Import( modname );
    string code = """
def testImport():
    print("something")
""";
    dynamic mine = PyModule.FromString( "testImport", code );
```

and this worked just fine. The question still stands- Why can't the `Py.Import` function load it from the file instead?